# xml to hive table. array of maps

Tags: xml, hive

My xml looks like this

```
<TAG>
  <REQUEST_ID>1</REQUEST_ID>
  <APPLICATION_ID>2</APPLICATION_ID>
  <EXTERNAL_SYSTEM_CODE>RB</EXTERNAL_SYSTEM_CODE>
  <CCM_CHECK>
    <CCM_CHECK_ID>101</CCM_CHECK_ID>
    <CCM_CHECK_RESULT>10</CCM_CHECK_RESULT>
  </CCM_CHECK>
  <VERIF_ANSWERS>
    <CHECK_CODE>101</CHECK_CODE>
    <QUESTION_CODE>1</QUESTION_CODE>
    <BOOKMARK_NUMBER>1</BOOKMARK_NUMBER>
    <ANSWER_VALUE>NN</ANSWER_VALUE>
  </VERIF_ANSWERS>
  <VERIF_ANSWERS>
    <CHECK_CODE>101</CHECK_CODE>
    <QUESTION_CODE>2</QUESTION_CODE>
    <BOOKMARK_NUMBER>1</BOOKMARK_NUMBER>
    <ANSWER_VALUE>NN</ANSWER_VALUE>
  </VERIF_ANSWERS>
</TAG>
```

this is how I create a table from it

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE s_sourcedata.evkuzmin_test_xml(
  request_id string
  , application_id string
  , external_system_code string
  , ccm_check map<string, string>
  , verif_answers array<struct<verif_answer:array<map<string, string>>>>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  "column.xpath.request_id"="/TAG/REQUEST_ID/text()",
  "column.xpath.application_id"="/TAG/APPLICATION_ID/text()",
  "column.xpath.external_system_code"="/TAG/EXTERNAL_SYSTEM_CODE/text()",
  "column.xpath.ccm_check"="/TAG/CCM_CHECK/*",
  "column.xpath.verif_answers"="/TAG")
STORED AS
INPUTFORMAT 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION '/storage/s_sourcedata/db/evkuzmin_test_xml'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  "xmlinput.start"="<TAG",
  "xmlinput.end"="</TAG>"
);
```

which results in the following

```
1,2,RB,"{""CCM_CHECK_ID"":""101"",""CCM_CHECK_RESULT"":""10""}","[{""verif_answer"":null}]"
```

How can i turn `verif_answers` into an array of key valur pairs like I did for `ccm_check`?

I tried doing it the same way I did for `ccm_check`? but got only the first `VERIF_ANSWERS`.

The number of `VERIF_ANSWERS` can vary. In this case there are 2? but there can be 0 or 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE myxml(
  request_id string
  , application_id string
  , external_system_code string
  , ccm_check map<string, string>
  , verif_answers array<map<string, string>>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  "column.xpath.request_id"="/TAG/REQUEST_ID/text()",
  "column.xpath.application_id"="/TAG/APPLICATION_ID/text()",
  "column.xpath.external_system_code"="/TAG/EXTERNAL_SYSTEM_CODE/text()",
  "column.xpath.ccm_check"="/TAG/CCM_CHECK/*",
  "column.xpath.verif_answers"="/TAG/VERIF_ANSWERS/*")
STORED AS
INPUTFORMAT 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION 'file:///home/cloudera/xmlfiles'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  "xmlinput.start"="<TAG",
  "xmlinput.end"="</TAG>"
);

select myxml.verif_answers from myxml;

INFO  : OK
+----------------------------------------------------+--+
|                myxml.verif_answers                 |
+----------------------------------------------------+--+
| [{"CHECK_CODE":"101"},{"QUESTION_CODE":"1"},{"BOOKMARK_NUMBER":"1"},{"ANSWER_VALUE":"NN"},{"CHECK_CODE":"101"},{"QUESTION_CODE":"2"},{"BOOKMARK_NUMBER":"1"},{"ANSWER_VALUE":"NN"}] |
+----------------------------------------------------+--+
1 row selected (0.306 seconds)
```