# xml to hive table SAXParseException

Tags: xml, hive

I have a following xml

```
<tns:TAG>
<REQUEST_ID>1</REQUEST_ID>
<APPLICATION_ID>2</APPLICATION_ID>
<EXTERNAL_SYSTEM_CODE>CF</EXTERNAL_SYSTEM_CODE>
<CCM_CHECK>
<CCM_CHECK_ID>44</CCM_CHECK_ID>
<CCM_CHECK_RESULT>21</CCM_CHECK_RESULT>
</CCM_CHECK>
</tns:TAG>
```

If I remove tns: from it, I can make a hive table that will read it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49433596/xml-to-hive-table-array-of-maps)

But if I leave it, I get the following error

```
java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 42; The prefix "tns" for element "tns:WSCCMVerifyApplicationResultRequest" is not bound.
```

The only thing I can think of, is parsing the files beforehand and removing all this `tns:` elements. I guess something like `regexp_replace()` will do it. But my question is, is there any other way? At the moment I create the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include `namespace` in your file which will get rid of this error. Something like this

```
<tns:TAG xmlns:tns="http://localhost">
  <REQUEST_ID>1</REQUEST_ID>
  <APPLICATION_ID>2</APPLICATION_ID>
```

**Update**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE myxml(
      request_id string
  , application_id string
  , external_system_code string
  , ccm_check map<string, string>
  , verif_answers array<map<string, string>>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  "column.xpath.request_id"="//*[local-name()='REQUEST_ID']/text()",
  "column.xpath.application_id"="//*[local-name()='APPLICATION_ID']/text()",
  "column.xpath.external_system_code"="//*[local-name()='EXTERNAL_SYSTEM_CODE']/text()",
  "column.xpath.ccm_check"="//*[local-name()='CCM_CHECK']/*",
  "column.xpath.verif_answers"="//*[local-name()='VERIF_ANSWERS']/*"
)
STORED AS
INPUTFORMAT 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION 'file:///home/cloudera/xmlfiles'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  "xmlinput.start"="<tns:TAG",
  "xmlinput.end"="</tns:TAG>"
);
```

Comment: Now I just get nulls. I tried the scrip from the link and changing table properties to `tns:TAG` and path to `/tns:TAG/REQUEST_ID/text()`. Still nulls.